# Семьдесят, восемьдесят, но девяносто?

Tags: словообразование, числительные

Скажите, пожалуйста: почему мы говорим семь**десят**, восемь**десят**, но девяно**сто**? И семь**сот**, восемь**сот**, но девять**сот**. Если вопрос не понятен - пишите! Спасибо заранее. Жду.

Comment: @MaksimV2013 Пробелы надо ставить после знаков препинания, а не до них.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен, формулируйте, пожалуйста, свои мысли грамотнее.

Comment: Несмотря на то что вопрос признали непонятным, сказалось много ответов:)

Answer (score 6):

Приведу краткое пояснение из  "Справочника по элементарной математике" (автор - М. Я. Выгодский, Москва, "Наука", 1982) :

"Слово *девяносто* не представляет исключения ... но оно образовано по другому способу (**девять-дО-ста**). Этим же способом составляются числительные 80 и 90 в тюркских языках (татарский : сигез - 8, сиксен - 80; тугыз - 9, туксан - 90) и числительные 70, 80, 90 в готском (древнегерманском) языке (**sibuntehund**, то есть "семь под сто" и т.д.)"

Можно добавить, что со временем "девять-дО-ста" преобразилось в "девяносто" ("путем диссимиляции согласных; второе "д" было заменено на "н", могло повлиять и слово "девятнадцать" " - указывает Лев Успенский) см. ниже комментарий

Comment: Да уж, Марк Яковлевич - голова...

Comment: Купите себе очки или протрите глаза :
"
"В татарском языке числа первого
десятка называются: бер ( 1 ), ике ( 2), еч
( 3 ), дурт (4 ), биш ( 5 ), алтын (6 ), жиде
( 7 ), сигез ( 8 ), тугыз ( 9), ун ( 10). Десятки
же именуются: егерме ( 20), утыз ( 30),
кырык ( 40), илле (50 ), алтмыш ( 60),
житмеш ( 70), сиксен ( 80), туксан ( 90).
Наряду с названием «иез» для
числительного 100 существует
наименование «сан»; это же слово
может означать и 40."

Comment: Объяснение из Этим. словаря школьника Льва Успенского : "ДЕВЯНОСТО.

  До XIII - XIV веков в употреблении была форма этого числительного, общая
всем славянам, - девять десять. С XIV века ее вытеснило новое слово, вероятно,
образовавшееся из сочетания "девять до ста" ("девять десятков до сотни")
путем диссимиляции согласных (см. стр. 22); второе "д" было заменено на "н".
Могло повлиять и слово "девятнадцать"." Проще пареной репы разжевано, молодец автор! [Почему не иначе](http://www.pochemyneinache.com/alfavit/5/str98.html)

Comment: 3. Недостаток этой версии в том, что там где у народов принято считать (100-10), как например в татарском или хантском, там и в низших порядках тоже самое (10-1), у нас же и девять. и девятнадцать в эту модель не вписываются. хотя в целом версия десять до ста вполне логична.

Answer (score 4):

С "девятьсот" вроде всё понятно, этимология легко читаемая - девять сотен.
С "девяносто" история поинтересней. Единого мнения появления этого странного числа нет. Известно, что это числительное сугубо восточнославянское, ни у западных, ни у южных славян ничего подобного нет. Первое упоминания этого слова относится к 60-70 годам 12 века. Попробую перечислить версии появления:

1. Семереньи О.; Постепенная трансформация; девять десятъ - девядесъто - девядосъто - девяносъто.
2. От праславянского невенА-съто - девяносъто (под влиянием слова девять), ср. лат nona-ginta, но стоит отметить, что вопреки мнению автора версии, Ф. Прусика, на и.-е 90 восстанавливается как "newn(m)kont".
3. Версия Соболевского А.И.; возникло от того, славяне считали не только сотнями, но и девятками. см. тридевять земель, тридевятое царство.
4. ЭССЯ: Девятичное сто возникло уже в индо-европейском языке.
5. Аникин А.Е.; малая (девятная) сотня.
6. Сакральная значимость числа 90, потребовала другого слова.
7. Десять до ста - десядосъто - девяносъто.

В общем, причины появления этого слова до сих пор не ясны.

Comment: >Сакральная значимость числа 90, потребовала другого слова.  
 
Это не версия, а причина. Сама по себе ничего не объясняет. Как и №3. 

№1 и  №7 - повторяются.
№4 - непонятно.  Что такое девятичное сто?

>на праславянский 90 восстанавливается как "newn(m)kont".
Откуда это? Праславянский  - классические сатем-язык.

Comment: "Что такое девятичное сто?"  
Это число сто в девятичной системе счёта. В математическом виде эта система выглядит так - 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 20...  Правда при таком подходе, сакральным должно быть число 81, а не 90, но наслоения одной системы на другую возможны, поэтому и не сал бы их отметать полностью.
Восстановление праславянского девяносто осуществил О. Семереньи.

Comment: >Это число сто в девятичной системе счёта  

Это ниже всякой критики. В девят**еричной** ([тыц][1]) системе 100(9) - это число, записываемое в системе десятиричной как 81. Все остальное - домыслы.

[1]: http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/rus_eng_mathematics/2238/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9

Comment: 3. Есть версии, я их озвучил с указанием авторства. Претензии по поводу того, что версии неправильные, адресуйте непосредственно авторам, про 81, я уже писал.

Comment: >Есть версии, я их озвучил с указанием авторства.  

Авторов вижу. Версий - нет. Судит о правильности неназванной явно вещи не берусь. Поэтому адресую Вам, как автору этого списка.
А вот что и как мне делать, я как-нибудь разберусь без Вашей помощи.

Answer (score 3):

Мы говорим ровно то, что содержит язык. А "почему" - это вопрос, ответа обычно не имеющий. Потому, что в языке есть такие слова. Нет логики, нет какой-то конкретной причины того, что слова образовались именно такими.

Могу только сказать, как эти слова образовались. Семьсот, восемьсот, девятьсот - это семь, восемь, девять сотен. Семьдесят, восемьдесят - восемь десятков. Что тут непонятного - не знаю. 
Вот с *девяносто* - сложнее. В славянских (и, если не ошибаюсь, домонгольских) источниках зафиксирована только форма *девятьдесят*. Позднее (по одной из версий) появилась форма *десятсто* или *десятносто* - т.е. "десять до ста", по форме напоминающая "одиннадцать", "двенадцать" и т.д., только противоположного смысла. Дальше в *десятностно* произошла замена первого "с" на "в", видимо не без влияния регулярной формы *девятьдесят* и упрощение согласных.

Answer (score 2):

А мне кажется вполне убедительной версия Жолобова: http://www.drevnyaya.ru/vyp/stat/s2_16_3.pdf    -Десятичная система возникла в результате отражения природных объектов с постоянной структурой ( 10 пальцев обеих рук).
Образование числительного 90 связано с важным событием – строительством десятинной церкви (996 год) – речь о десятине: всякая сотня любой прибыли становилась особой девятичной сотней – сто превращалось в 90.Это  реальное сто, но оно включало в себя десятину и в любой момент могло превратиться в девять десять. На ранних грамотах этого времени было написано "девяносто"(девятьное сто), стёрто и поверх написано "девятьдесят". 90 – это полное сто после вычета десятины.Долго не могли понять, почему в берестяных грамотах неполное сто-это 80, а не 90. А это как раз объясняет.

Девятьное сто – девятичное сто - отражение девятичной системы.
Греко-славянская буквенная цифирь насчитывала 27 (трижды девять знаков) В каждый из 3 разрядов входило девять буквоцифр. Вроде бы всё объясняется.

Comment: Людмила, но там дет ничего оригинального. Он и сам пишет, что  это лишь подтверждение основной весрии Семереньи.  
Я правда почему-то не могу открыть документ целиком, зависает на третьей странице, попробую позже, но смысл мне понятен. А вот термин "девятичное сто" по-прежнему вызывает резкое отторжение, если это конечно система счисления, а не что-то еще хитрое.

Comment: Греко-славянская буквенная цифирь насчитывала 27 (трижды девять знаков_ ... Вроде бы всё объясняется.

Никоим образом. Система по сути оставалась лесятиричной. Или если восем строго - то никакой, ибо нет позиционного сдвига. Но в лснове записи все равно лежало число десять, любое число записывалось как (Nсотен=Mлесятков+Кединиц). 

Но это отдельный разговор. Подобное объяснение и не нужно. С тем, что 9 играло особую роль я вполне готов согласиться. 

>Долго не могли понять, почему в берестяных грамотах неполное сто-это 80, а не 90  

Не слышал о таком. Тем более не могну понять "объяснение"

Comment: Людмила, "девятичная" система - это фикция. Значимых цифр и сейчас всего 9, а ноль обозначает разряд числа. 10 = 1 десяток. Если Вы хотите ввести девятичную систему, то 9 будет обозначаться как 10. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,10. В двоичной системе 2 это 10. Славянская I обозначала 10, АI = 11, ВI = 12... Если, к примеру, четырнадцать - это "четыре на десять", то в каком же месте можно углядеть "девятичную" систему. Сама церковная десятина - это что?

Comment: Прочитал статью. Подгонка неимоверная о десятине. Доказывается, что 80 это "неполное сто" такими словами : "А не будет полна ста у домочадца, а осмь десять выдаст, а дополнительные 20 гривен возьмет у князя в клети" (!!!) Автор статьи "скромно" не замечает число 20, приводит его в записи - "К под титлом". Вместо рассмотрения вопроса о форме слова 90 - сплошные выдумки о десятинах и тд. и тп. "Девятичная" система на Руси им, кстати, отвергается.

Comment: > Да то же римское обозначение - IX - это " сто минус десять"

Во-первых, IX - это 9 ("10-1"). А 90 будет как XC ("100-10"). 
А во-вторых, римляне были большими оригиналами. У них и система непозиционная была, и числа типа четырех тоже записывались специальным образом (1 - I, 2 - II, 3 - III, 4 - IV!).

Comment: Вот видите, я-то спросонок ошибся))), а научный работник Жолобов вешает лапшу на уши сознательно! Обыкновенную запись, что не хватило до полной сотни двадцати гривен у кого-то, он выдает за доказательство(!) наименования числа 80 - "неполное сто". Умопомрачение полное... А если бы у человека 70 гривен оказалось, до полных ста надо было бы еще 30 добавить, во как))))))) Облом, ребята!

Answer (score 0):

Устному счёту предшествовал счёт на пальцах, который, дрейфуя в сторону больших чисел, чем 5, преображался в парный, где пара пальцев — не просто два, а два (зеркально) одинаковых пальца на руках. Посчитаем. Начав счёт с мизинцев левой и правой рук, окончим его десяткой на правой руке; начнём с правого мизинца — окончим большим левой руки, и тогда на месте 9-го пальца окажется 10-й, и наоборот. Девять в таком случае **равна** десяти, как и другие пальцы (числом) попарно равны. Побывавший 10-м может ли быть просто 9-м? Поэтому числа, при небольшом исключении, у нас парные: родные и графемой цифр, и словом.