# Происхождение числительного 90

Tags: математика

Какое происхождение числительного 90? Прошу помощи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Повтор.
[Семьдесят, восемьдесят, но девяносто?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17679)

Answer (score 0):

Я уже отвечал на этот вопрос :  [Семьдесят, восемьдесят, но девяносто?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/17679/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8C%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82-%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE)